Shall proofs be externalised?
I might have a reached a point in a proof I’m writing in which I can take two different directions:

I can complete my proof by relying on someone else’s theorem;
I can complete my proof without relying on anyone else’s theorem.

Option 1 allows me to more-or-less quickly complete my proof; but it forces interested readers to check another paper. Option 2 gives a self-contained and complete proof of my theorem, but it may take me some serious time. Furthermore, the resulting proof if I follow Option 2 is much, much longer than the resulting proof if I follow Option 1.
In case it matters: the theorem I can rely upon was published in one of my discipline’s top journals many years ago, but it has not gained widespread attention (i.e., it has not been widely cited). Given the quality of the journal that published said theorem, and the many years that have passed since its publication; I assume said theorem to be true. I have tried to verify all the steps in that proof; and while the theorem seems true, I haven’t been able to verify all its steps (it’s a difficult proof, even for experienced practitioners of my discipline).
On the one hand, I understand that a self-contained proof might be better; but on the other, I understand that theorems exist so that other researchers can build upon them. So, which of these two options is generally considered better practice?

Option 3: Do option 1, but include the old proof of the theorem in an appendix.

Why not do both?  Include the proof by reference, certainly. But, as you appear uncertain whether or not the referenced proof is familiar or firmly established, include your work around.

I wouldn't say that one option is always better than the other. The best thing to do (which you are already doing!) is to weigh the pros and cons of both options, and hybrid options such as those suggested in previous comments.

It depends what a user accepts as a known theorem. I would , for example , accept a proof based on Fermats last theorem although I will never understand Wiles proof for it. If option 2 is feasible it cannot be a bad idea to show this alternative as well for interested readers.
